# frames buffer managing using multithreading c#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I want to work with frames of a video, but processing in every frame decrease Frame rate. 
Then I decide to buffer frames and process every frame on a thread. I put every frame in `input` Queue and process them in `thrds` queue by `detection` function and finally put processed frames in `output` Queue.

My problem is when my program runs, each 5 frames(5 is size of buffers) shown with good framerate but after this 5 frame the program stopped a second and show 5 next frames good!
I use `emguCV` for capturing video.
for managing threads I use this class:

```
 class Manage_buffer
    {

        public Queue<Bitmap> Input;
        public Queue<Bitmap> Output;
        public Queue<Thread> thrds;
        FaceDetectionDll.Class1 fdclass;

        public Manage_buffer()
        {

            Input = new System.Collections.Generic.Queue<Bitmap>();
            Output = new System.Collections.Generic.Queue<Bitmap>();
            thrds = new System.Collections.Generic.Queue<Thread>();
            fdclass = new FaceDetectionDll.Class1();

        }

        public void Add(Bitmap bmp)
        {

            lock (Input)
            {

                Bitmap n = new Bitmap(bmp);
                Input.Enqueue(n);
            }

            Thread thrd = new Thread(new ThreadStart(detection));
            thrd.IsBackground = true;       
            thrds.Enqueue(thrd);

            if (Input.Count > 4)
            {
               Parallel.Invoke(tstar);
            }

        }

        void tstar()
        {
            while (thrds.Count > 0)
            {
                Thread t = thrds.Dequeue();
                t.Start();
            }

        }



        void detection()
        {
            Bitmap b = new Bitmap(1, 1);   
            lock (Input)
            {   
                if (Input.Count > 0)
                {    
                    Bitmap bp = new Bitmap(Input.Dequeue());    
                    Image<Rgb, Byte> currentFrame = new Image<Rgb, Byte>(bp);                 
                    fdclass.FaceDetectionFunc((int)currentFrame.Ptr);
                    b = new Bitmap(currentFrame.ToBitmap());
                    bp.Dispose();
                    currentFrame.Dispose();
                }
            }
            Output.Enqueue(b);
        }
    }
```

my main code in form window is:

```
....
mgclass=new Manage_buffer();
Application.Idle += ProcessFrame;
.....
 private void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs arg)
        {
            Image<Bgr, Byte> ImageFrame = c.QueryFrame();  //line 1
            Bitmap frame = ImageFrame.ToBitmap();
                   mgclass.Add(frame);
                   if (mgclass.Output.Count > 0)
                   {
                       frame = mgclass.Output.Dequeue();
                       pictureBox1.Image = frame;  
                   }       
                Thread.Sleep((int)(1000.0 / 25));//frame rate of vide is 25fps
        }
```

Comment: Don't lock on public properties/fields - now any code with access to your public property/field can create a lock and break your code. Make a private object for locking in your class.

Comment: What does `fdclass.FaceDetectionFunc` do? It takes an integer and doesn't return anything. Is it modifying it's own internal state? If so, what does it do with it?

Comment: `facedetectionfunc` function result is on its parameter. this is not important at all. I processed my frames trusty.I want show a frame after processed but this code show frames after output size is 5 and after 5 frame don't show any things for a second.